# Can I install gnome or KDE plasma desktop environment in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (running in WSL 2) in windows 11?

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, kde, desktop-environments

I'm currently running Windows 11 (22H2), beta build with windows insider program, and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS in WSL 2.

The lack of keyboard shortcut really urges me to switch to Ubuntu, can I have a parallel desktop environment such as Gnome or KDE Plasma, which I can switch to as per requirement ?

I installed WSL 2 to ease up the manual compilation or other terminal stuff I use, such as git or vim. The reason I'm not dual booting is that I use heavy IDEs such IntelliJ idea and Visual Studio, and some games too, with C drive taking up 300gb (75gb free) out of 500gb, it's not possible to have dual boot with IDE on both OS.

Answer (score 0):

you can install both gnome and kubuntu desktop and change them after logout or at login screen

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop kubuntu-desktop
```

you can also install ubuntu minimum desktop search package ubuntu desktop minimal instead of full package to save space

you better install ubuntu as dual boot it take only 5 Gb + swap file around 1 gb at fresh install
shrink and create 30 - 50 Gb ext4 partition install ubuntu on that
remove wsl / ubuntu to free space
You must backup your data, files before following steps given above